# MaterialUI DropDownMenu Multiple select using react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get a DropDownMenu to work using the option multiple=true

so currently my component looks like code below. This works fine.

but now i want to enable the multiple selection

this is were i am kindof in the weeds. I would love a simple example.

some questions.

1. When creating the MenuItems , i assume this does not change?
2. How do you do the  MenuItem disabled entry
3. the value that is an array. this is an array of all the possible values?

the doc says about the property multiple:

> If true, value must be an array and the menu will support multiple
>   selections.

```
var options = this.props.optionsarray.map((o, i) => {
        return <MenuItem value={ o[this.props.optionsvaluename] } key={i} primaryText={ o[this.props.optionstextname] } />
    })

    return (
        <div className="t-input-container" >
            <div className="t-custom-input-container">
                <DropDownMenu
                    style={ !this.props.dropDownMenu ? {border: '1px solid #efefef'} : this.props.dropDownMenu }
                    selectedMenuItemStyle={ !this.props.selectedMenuItemStyle  ? {color: '#c31da3'} : this.props.selectedMenuItemStyle }
                    value={this.props.value}
                    multiple={this.props.multiple}
                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
                    underlineStyle={{left: -10}}
                    labelStyle={ !this.props.labelStyle ? {color: this.props.labelColor, fontWeight: 200} : this.props.labelStyle }
                    menuItemStyle={ !this.props.menuItemStyle ? {fontWeight: 100} : this.props.menuItemStyle }
                    autoWidth={true} >
                    <MenuItem disabled value={''} key={''} primaryText={this.props.defaultText} />
                    {options}
                </DropDownMenu>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Are you not passing multiple as true to the component then?

Comment: in this example i am not, but i trying to get it to work with that property set to  true, and not exactly sure all that changes i need to make

Comment: If you only want a single value selected then `value={[this.props.value]}` unless value is already an array of course.

Answer (score 0):

Created a sample which is allowing multiselection.

```
import React from 'react'
import { DropDownMenu, MenuItem } from "material-ui";
import { MuiThemeProvider, getMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles'
import {deepOrange500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors'

const styles = {
    customWidth: {
        width: 200,
    },
};

export default class DropDownMenuSimpleExample extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: [1] };
        this.muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
            palette: {
                accent1Color: deepOrange500
            }
            , userAgent: props.userAgent
        })
    }

    handleChange (event, index, value)
    {
        debugger
        this.setState({ value })
};

    render() {
        return (

            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={this.muiTheme}>
                <div>
                    <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} multiple={true} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} >
                        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Never" />
                        <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
                        <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
                        <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Weekends" />
                        <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Weekly" />
                    </DropDownMenu>
                    <br />

                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>


        );
    }
}
```

You can use the same way to support your scenario.

- First thing would be  `multiple={true}`
- Next make sure your `value={this.state.value}` in `DropDownMenu`  is an array. (In the above example, I made it an array in state.)
- Then in onChange event, setting the selected values to state again.